# Copy data from nested array to associative table

Tags: plsql

I have a collection with type nested table and having millions of records

I want to copy data from this table to another. How do we frame the INSERT clause for this seems challenging:

Second table in which I want to insert is associative array.

I don't have enough information with me but it would be really helpful if you show me how copy data from one collection type to another.

Comment: Use the "edit" link below your question and show us complete declarations of your source collection and of your target collection.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your expected functionality in a pure PLSQL function/procedure via looping over the nested table coll. and saving the items into an assoc. array.

**Note** that processing collections with millions of items will make your DBAs probably sad or even angry due to excessive server memory consumption.

Comment: Could you please provide me some example?

Comment: My only problem is how to save 2 dimensional structure in one dimensional

Comment: You haven't mentioned anything about the structure being 2-dimensional in your original question. Please fix it.